# Executing SQL on Pandas Dataframe and storing results in same Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, teradata

[image: current dataframe]

I have a data frame that looks like the image above.  What I want to do is loop through the SQL statements under SQL_SCRIPT, execute them, and store the results in the next column over which would be called 'RESULTS'.  When I just try and execute it (without storing it anywhere) it runs fine, but when I try and store the results in a new dataframe column it errors out with:

```
ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns
```

Here is the code:

```
def run_tests(self):
    s = self.connection()
    df = self.retrieve_sql()
    df_type = df.loc[df['STEP_TYPE'] == 'T']
    df_to_list = df_type[['TABLE_NM', 'TEST_TABLE_NM', 'SQL_SCRIPT']]
    print(df_to_list)
    for sql_script in df_to_list['SQL_SCRIPT']:
        df_to_list.loc['RESULTS'] = pd.read_sql(sql_script,s)
    print(df_to_list)
```

Instead of read_sql I have also tried just using the session execute, which also works but I'm not sure how to store the results to the dataframe going that route:

```
def run_tests(self):
    s = self.connection()
    df = self.retrieve_sql()
    df_type = df.loc[df['STEP_TYPE'] == 'T']
    df_to_list = df_type[['TABLE_NM', 'TEST_TABLE_NM', 'SQL_SCRIPT']]
    print(df_to_list)
    for sql_script in df_to_list['SQL_SCRIPT']:
        s.execute(sql_script)
```

Here is the connection function, if needed:

```
def connection(self):
    con = self.load_json_file()
    cfg_dsn = con['config']['dsn']
    cfg_usr = con['config']['username']
    cfg_pwd = con['config']['password']

    udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appName="DataAnalysis", version="1.0", logConsole=False)
    session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", dsn=cfg_dsn, username=cfg_usr, password=cfg_pwd)

    return session
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider running [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) on the column of SQL strings.

```
def run_tests(self):
    s = self.connection()
    c = s.cursor()              # OPEN CURSOR
    df = self.retrieve_sql()

    df_type = df.loc[df['STEP_TYPE'] == 'T']
    df_to_list = df_type[['TABLE_NM', 'TEST_TABLE_NM', 'SQL_SCRIPT']]
    print(df_to_list)

    # NEW METHOD TO RUN QUERY
    def sql_run(x):   
        c.execute(x)
        if c.rowcount > 0:
           res = c.fetchone()[0]
        else:
           res = np.nan
        return res

    df_to_list['RESULTS'] = df_to_list['SQL_SCRIPT'].apply(sql_run)
    print(df_to_list)
```

Comment: Thank you @Parfait.  This is returning 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable'.  I think this may be because some SELECT queries aren't count(*) and they return nothing (not 0) and that is expected.  Is there a way to handle this?  By putting a default value in the dataframe cell instead?  I am not sure.  Sorry, I didnt include that in the original question but I think that may be the issue?

Comment: Add a handler in apply function. See update with `if` checking cursor row count.

Comment: Thank you Parfait!  That worked perfectly.  Very, very much appreciated.